# How-To export all "Keychain Access" passwords into plain text / search for specific (compromised) passwords

Tags: security, password, keychain, sonoma

How-To export all "Keychain Access" passwords into plain text. I wish to search for specific passwords, because some of my passwords were leaked.

I did a web search and found [Import and export keychain items using Keychain Access on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/import-and-export-keychain-items-kyca35961/mac) from support.apple.com.

> You can export some keychain items (for example, certificates and
> keys) from one computer and then import them into Keychain Access on
> another.
>
> **Note: You can’t export passwords from Keychain Access.**

Is there no workaround to export all passwords?

Some of my passwords are compromised and I don't know exactly what (which services..) I used them for. Unfortunately I had made password-reuse, shame on me.

Comment: I've added [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/468911/24324) to one of the suggested duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## System Settings

Check the **Security Recommendations** for your credentials [in System Settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/105115) on macOS 14. This should list compromised entries.

The <kbd>▼ …</kbd> button within **System Settings > Passwords** includes an **Export All Passwords…** menu item.

## Export Keychain Files

If your passwords are stored in local keychain files, and not on Apple's servers, then you can use [Keysafe](https://miln.eu/keysafe/) to export the contents to a text based file:

```
./keysafe -path ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db -export ~/Desktop/exported.tgz
```

I wrote `keysafe` to be able to access my credentials without needing a Mac and to be able to [bulk export my Keychain files](https://miln.eu/keysafe/#how-to-export-a-keychain).

Keysafe is not free and requires a licence to see the encrypted contents; without a licence the contents are hidden.

Comment: See also https://github.com/juuso/keychaindump and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184897/how-to-dump-the-content-of-keychain-from-the-shell

Comment: Unfortunately `keychaindump` [no longer works](https://github.com/juuso/keychaindump/issues) with recent versions of macOS.